# How to turn-off autocompletion inside strings in RubyMine?

Tags: ide, rubymine

In specs very often RubyMine is hanging when I writing the spec description string. It seems like it is searching for something. I suspect autocompletion.

Where can I configure autocompletion settings or set just how to behave inside strings? What can be the possible cause of this hanging when I write strings in spec description?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't a way to turn off autocompletion for specific circumstances, but the settings that are available are in the preferences menu > Editor > General > Code Completion.